# SQL select all by date

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, sql-order-by

Im new with SQL.
I have 3  tables like below:

Table client: a list of clients with their first and last names, full address
Table Produit: a list of articles sent on the web site containing the name of the article, the country where it was manufactured, and its price
Table Actions: a list of all transactions done by clients with the time of the transactions.

**Output desired**

get the revenue generated by all clients where date is 2018 in each country, and ordered by the highest revenue first.

Comment: Please can you provide table structures for each so its easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this (which assumes that the transactions table has the name of the article, and the produit table has a date field with a date data type):

```
select 
a.client, 
sum(c.price) as revenue

from client as a 

inner join actions as b 
on a.client = b.client

inner join produit c
on c.article = b.article

where year(c.date) = '2018'

group by 
a.client 

order by 
sum(c.price);
```

Comment: `year` is a product spesific function (not included in the standard SQL) whereas we don't know the DBMS.

Comment: There must be something in ANSI that would work. I use an Oracle DB, but I'll take a look when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to include the country, see highest revenue first, & use ANSI function for year.

```
SELECT c.client_id,
       c.first_name,
       c.last_name,
       p.country,
       SUM(a.amount) amount
FROM   client c
       JOIN actions a ON c.client_id = a.client_id
       JOIN produit p ON a.article_id = p.article_id
WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.transaction_date) = '2018'
GROUP BY c.client_id,
         c.first_name,
         c.last_name,
         p.country
ORDER BY SUM(a.amount) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you but @Acroyear  it doesn't work **error** near line 27: near "FROM": syntax error